# DIV fill remaining height when the DIV above changes its height dynamically

Tags: html, css, height

Is there a CSS solution for having a DIV (`D2`) filling the remaining parent element height when the DIV above (`D1`) dynamically changes its size?

```
|-------------------|    |-------------------|    |-------------------|
| some content   D1 |    | some content   D1 |    | some content   D1 |
| +                 |    | more content      |    | more content      |
|-------------------|    | +                 |    | even more         |
|                D2 |    |-------------------|    | +                 |
|                   |    |                D2 |    |-------------------|
|                   |    |                   |    |                D2 |
|                   |    |                   |    |                   |
|                   |    |                   |    |                   |
|                   |    |                   |    |                   |
|-------------------|    |-------------------|    |-------------------|
```

`D1` also has a `max-height` and `overflow: scroll`.

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XumuF/1/) make the yellow (`d2`) fill the rest, whatever the dynamic content of `d1` is, without using javascript.

I have seen several question but none treat a dynamic height changing of the upper DIV (`D1`)

- [Div to fill remaing vertical space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875521/div-to-fill-remaing-vertical-space)
- [How to make a div height to fill available space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142977/how-to-make-a-div-height-to-fill-available-space)
- [Expand DIV vertically to fill the remaining space in nonfixed height column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122296/expand-div-vertically-to-fill-the-remaining-space-in-nonfixed-height-column)
- [How to fill 100% of remaining height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376558/how-to-fill-100-of-remaining-height)
- …

I can not use a Javascript solution. TABLEs are also fine instead of DIVs.

Answer (score 0):

***Check updated answer below.***

make structure like this

```
 div class=main  {
     div class=d1 {
          something 
          more stuff
          even more stuff
          }
     div class=d2{
            something
           }

}
```

css :

```
div main { 
      width 200 px; for example
      }
d1, d2 { 
      width 100%,
      and float:left
      }
```

now by doing this when d1 changes d2 automatically goes down, don't give `height` to any DIV

### Update : Using Flexbox property

```css
.main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 160px;
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.d1 {
  background: lime;
}
.d2 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
.d1,
.d2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="d1">
    d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1 d1
  </div>
  <div class="d2">
    d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2
  </div>
</div>
```

Now how much content is in `D1` doesn't matter, `D2` will take full height of `main` div.

Comment: This does not work since `d2` does not fill **the rest of the parent** http://jsfiddle.net/XumuF/

Comment: check this [http://jsfiddle.net/Nuwyn/](http://jsfiddle.net/Nuwyn/),
is this what you want ?

Comment: @shyammakwana.me Your fiddle does not do the job either. See http://jsfiddle.net/u5x8w7ym/ to see that `d2` overflows the bottom of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer more descriptive class names...

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font: 20px Verdana;
    height: 88vh;
    background: grey;
    padding: 5px;
}
.upper{
    flex: 1 1; /* grow shrink */
    background: lime;
}
.lower{
    flex: 1 1; /* grow shrink */
    background: yellow;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[image: Here's a screen shot from my fiddle]

https://jsfiddle.net/spencerw/zLcwq42s/52/